# Stacked Area Graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have studied other similar questions on SO, but can't seem to get this working for my data.

I am aiming for this result:

[image: desired output]

This is my data frame:

```
    Room    Direc   MB
    Alley-10    Rx  1
    Alley-11    Rx  7
    Alley-12    Rx  11
    Alley-10    Tx  23
    Alley-11    Tx  17
    Alley-12    Tx  20
```

When I run:

```
ggplot(tp, aes(x=Room,y=MB)) + geom_area(aes(fill=factor(Direc)))
```

I get this result:

[image: not working]

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 5):

This won't work because the `Room` variable is treated as a factor and thus doesn't make any sense to have continuous lines connecting.

Plotting:

```
ggplot(tp, aes(x=1:3, y=MB, fill=Direc)) +
   geom_area()
```

gives the result I think you're expecting.  You can then add:

```
ggplot(tp, aes(x=1:3, y=MB, fill=Direc)) +
   geom_area() +
   scale_x_discrete(labels=tp$Room)
```

to fix the labels.